# Is JSF managedBeans and JMX managedBeans the same?

Tags: jsf, jmx

Maybe a little bit stupid question, but is JSF managedBeans and JMX managedBeans the same?  Can I access, for example, JSF managedBean through JMX?

Answer (score 1):

No, JMX beans and JSF beans are completely different concepts. JSF beans are primarily accessible via EL expressions and JMX beans can be accessed using the standard Java management interfaces.